# If Z~N(0,1), find P(|Z|>1.12)? First year university statistics.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

If Z~N(0,1), find P(|Z|>1.12)?

Using table 4 of the New Cambridge Statistical tables, I have that the P(Z>1.12) is 1-P(z<1.12)= 0.131.

However I do not understand how I can work out P(|Z|>1.12)?

f

Comment: $$P(|Z|>1.12)=2P(Z>1.12)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
P(|Z|\ge 1.12) = P(Z \ge 1.12) + P(Z \le -1.12) =  1- \Phi(1.12) + 1-\Phi( 1.12)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$|Z|>1.12\equiv \{Z<-1.12\}\cup\{Z>1.12\}$. As $\{Z<-1.12\}\cap\{Z>1.12\}=\phi$ hence $$P(|Z|>1.12)=P(Z<-1.12)+P(Z>1.12)=\Phi(-1.12)+[1-\Phi(1.12)]=2\Phi(-1.12)$$ the last equality following from the fact that $\Phi(-1.12)=[1-\Phi(1.12)]$, where $\Phi(.)$ is the cumulative distribution function of $N(0,1)$ variable.